# Periodic coefficients of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If we have a continuous function $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and its complex Fourier coefficients are periodic, i.e. 
$$c(n) = c(n+k)$$
 for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, can we prove that $f$ is identically the zero function?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For all m you have

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |c(m+nk)|^2 \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |c(n)|^2 =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx$$

Comment: isn't there an extra 1/2pi term multiplied by the integral ?I mean this is Parseval theorem...

Comment: @HousamKak yes, ty

Comment: how does this make $f(x)$ identically zero?

Comment: i know Parseval... but really i have no idea how u got the left inequality... and also if we wanna prove the function zero shouldnt we be bounding the integral from the right somehow...

Comment: @HousamKak $$c(m+nk)=c(m)$$ for all $n$... How can an infinite sum of non-negative equal terms be finite? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier coefficients $c(m)$ tend to $0$ as $ m \to \pm \infty$. Hence, $c(n)=c(n+mk) \to 0$ as $ m \to \infty$ proving that $c_n=0$ for all $n$.